# Block fake users & fake ip addresses from using application

Tags: networking, ip, redirection, network-traffic, traffic-filtering

I am facing some issues when it comes to application's traffic & its users. The point is that users tend to sign-up/register on my SaaS application. They use(mostly for wrong purposes) the product for once and leave.

As the users are from a specific country, we tried blocking the IP address for that area, but users tend to change IP addresses via certain tools & continue to do the same!

What can be done in order to restrict such fake access of users to our application??

Comment: Don’t offer the service at all? Are these users somehow causing problems or what? Other than polluting the account database.

Comment: These users are actually using our product for collecting information (unauthentically). I am totally unsure if they are using the info for the false purposes or something. Moreso, they aren't even our customers. Even if they become one, they ask for reimbursement in some time of use.

Comment: There are a million ways to do it - make them use 2FA, so you've got their phone number… make them verify at least something. People are far less willing to give away their bank details...

Comment: They are ready to provide info while at the end they ask for refunds

Comment: So they're _real_ users, only they try to scam you? Now this definitely doesn't sound like a problem you can solve at a technical level.

Comment: You don't need to offer any refund if a service has already been used. They bought it, they used it. Tough. It's only physical goods that must be refunded on 'sale or return'.